# Total not getting in 2nd row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one dropdown and 2 textbox. I have a more then 1 row of same fields. When i do total it is done in 1st row but not getting total in 2nd row.

```js
var counter = 1;
counter++;
$(document).on('change, focusout', '.price,.qty', function() {
  var oproductname = $(this).val();
  var productQty = parseInt($('#productqty' + counter).val());
  var productPrice = parseFloat($('#orderedproduct' + counter).find(':selected').data('price'));
  var totalAmount = productQty * productPrice;

  $('#orderammount' + counter).val(totalAmount);


});
```

```html
<select name="orderedproduct" id="orderedproduct2" class="price">
              <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
              <option value="1" data-price="45.23">incarprot</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="50.00">incalcy</option>
 </select>

<input type="text" name="productqty" id="productqty2" class="gui-input" placeholder="Quantity">

<input type="text" name="orderammount" id="orderammount2" class="gui-input qty" disable placeholder="Total Amount">

<select name="orderedproduct" id="orderedproduct3" class="price">
              <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
              <option value="1" data-price="45.23">incarprot</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="50.00">incalcy</option>
 </select>

<input type="text" name="productqty" id="productqty3" class="gui-input" placeholder="Quantity">

<input type="text" name="orderammount" id="orderammount3" class="gui-input qty" disable placeholder="Total Amount">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why did you add the fiddle link as code block when you were told while submitting the question that you needed to provide actual code? Now the link can't even be used and there is no code in the question where it should be

Comment: check updated question @charlietfl

Comment: @shubhamshah check my answer, it works as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your `counter` variable, the way it is used, `counter` is never changed to 3 and the `Total Amount` is not shown for second row. So, for making it to work correctly, you can add a new attribute property in the `<select>` dropdown called `row` and then get this `row` value in `counter` which can be then used in the `id` selector.

```js
$(document).on('change, blur', '.price,.txtQuantity', function(){ 
debugger
    var oproductname = $(this).val();
    var counter = $(this).attr('row');
    var productQty = parseInt($('#productqty'+counter).val());
    var productPrice = parseFloat($('#orderedproduct'+counter).find(':selected').data('price'));
    var totalAmount = productQty * productPrice ; 
    
     $('#orderammount'+counter).val(totalAmount );
     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select name="orderedproduct" id="orderedproduct2" class="price" row='2'>
              <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
              <option value="1" data-price="45.23">incarprot</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="50.00">incalcy</option>
 </select>  
 
 <input type="text" name="productqty" id="productqty2" class="gui-input txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" row='2'>
 
 <input type="text" name="orderammount" id="orderammount2" class="gui-input qty" disable placeholder="Total Amount">
 
 <select name="orderedproduct" id="orderedproduct3" class="price" row='3'>
              <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
              <option value="1" data-price="45.23">incarprot</option>
              <option value="2" data-price="50.00">incalcy</option>
 </select>  
 
 <input type="text" name="productqty" id="productqty3" class="gui-input txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" row='3'>
 
 <input type="text" name="orderammount" id="orderammount3" class="gui-input qty" disable placeholder="Total Amount">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want one thing is that when i select product & enter quantity, total should be filled.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have added row attribute to the input text as well and changed the event to blur